# Post Data To a Web Service From Arduino

Tags: web-service

If you want to submit sensor data such as temperature to a remote server/database somewhere you need to use some kind of call to a web server since it isn't possible to connect directly to a database from the Arduino.

How do you post data to a JSON web service from an Arduino that's connected to the Internet?

Comment: What web service are you using?

Comment: It will be one I write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [aJson](https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson) library that allows you to work with JSON objects in Arduino.

However, depending on the complexity of your program, I would just do it manually to save memory. You may be able to just copy the functions you want out of the library.

Then check out the [WebClient](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebClient) library which has an example for making a POST request at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/WebClient) from Arduino docs.

In the "Post method request" code example just define your JSON as plain text like `char jsonData[] = "{name: 'yourName', data: 'yourData'}"` for example, and then call `byte postPage(char* domainBuffer,int thisPort,char* page,char* thisData)` function passing "jsonData" variable defined before for "thisData" parameter.

It worked for me, hope it helps.